# C#: Help determining selected node index in a TreeView. NullReferenceException error?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make it so I can run certain events when a node is selected in a TreeView. I run the code and I get an error that reads NullReferenceException was unhandled: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Any clues on how to overcome this obstacle?

```
    private void tvNodes_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (tvNodes.SelectedNode.Index)
        {
            case 0:
                //first item
                break;

            case 1:
                //second item
                break;

            case 2:
                //third item
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

`tvNodes.SelectedNode` is not the same as the node you clicked on, and may be null. Change to use `e.Node.Index` instead. And I'm paranoid; I'd probably *still* check that `e.Node` isn't `null` first...

```
    if(e.Node == null) return;
    switch (e.Node.Index)
    {
        case 0:
            //first item
            break;

        case 1:
            //second item
            break;

        case 2:
            //third item
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void tvNodes_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e) {
    var index = null != e.Node ? e.Node.Index : -1;
    switch (index) {
        case 0:
            //first item
            break;
        case 1:
            //second item
            break;
        case 2:
            //third item
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to make it so I can run
>   certain events when a node is **selected**
>   in a TreeView.

Looks like you need to use AfterSelect event instead of NodeMouseClick:

```
private void tvNodes_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
     switch (e.Node.Index)
    {
        case 0:
            //first item
            break;

        case 1:
            //second item
            break;

        case 2:
            //third item
            break;
    }

}
```

You should note, that AfterSelect occurs only once after Node selection changed whether via keyboard or by mouse. NodeMouseClick occured every time Node clicked with mice. In MSDN:

> This event occurs when the user clicks
>   any portion of a tree node with the
>   mouse, **including the plus sign (+) or
>   minus sign (-)** that indicates whether
>   the node is collapsed or expanded.

So SelectedNode may be null, because user clicks on [+] or [-].